# Monitoring for failure and quickly restarting systemd service

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ffmpeg, systemd

I am running a 24/7 youtube stream on Ubuntu. My ffmpeg command is wrapped in a systemd service. On several occasions the ffmpeg command has failed and systemd has not restarted quickly enough to keep the youtube stream alive. When this happens I need to daemon-reload and restart the systemd service.

To counter this I have written a bash script that checks the log for stream ending errors, however, it does not seem to be working. I have had failures since implementing this script, and it did not seem to have been triggered.

two questions:

1. is there a more efficient way to do what I am doing?
2. if not, can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

RESET=0

while true; do
    # Get the current time minus 1 minute
    LAST_1_MINUTE=$(date -d '1 minute ago' '+%b %e %H:%M:%S')
    
    # Run the command to check for the error within the last minute
    if journalctl --since "$LAST_1_MINUTE" | grep -qi "Error writing trailer"; then
        if [ $RESET -lt 1 ]; then
            # Perform actions if error is detected
            sudo systemctl daemon-reload && \
            echo "Restarting master.service by monitor.sh script at $(date)" >> /var/log/monitor.log && \
            sudo systemctl restart master.service
            RESET=2
        fi
    else
        RESET=$((RESET - 1))
    fi

    # Wait for 20 seconds before the next iteration
    sleep 20
done
```

Comment: systemd's automatic restart support is entirely configurable. If you want it to have less delay, to be willing to restart more times, or to have any other difference in behavior you want -- that's just configuration; there's no need for a separate script.

Comment: If you're using `ExecStart` to _directly_ invoke ffmpeg, and you want ffmpeg to be more promptly killed on emitting the error message in question, then the script it might make sense to write would be a wrapper that runs ffmpeg as a child and monitors its output, forcing an immediate exit to both processes when the error takes place. (Make sure you have systemd configured to kill the entire cgroup, not just the main PID, when shutting down the service -- that way you can't get a stray copy of ffmpeg left behind after the wrapper script itself is killed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you. Yes, I believe that systemd should not require an additional solution or monitoring script.

After looking through my logs, it seems that ffmpeg restarts immediately, but my stream still goes offline for lack of input. Would a short delay in the restart prevent the failure? (I realize this may be going out of scope of the topic)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Really depends on details that aren't provided. What kind of protocol is this? If you can use something UDP-based it'll be a more seamless transition. That said, I could conceive of wanting something in the middle -- having a service that takes the stream from your camera (or similar) and forwards it if it's available, or sends frames from an apology message or such otherwise. _Personally_ the toolkit I'd reach for would be gstreamer, but it's been a while since this is a space I've done much plumbing in.

Comment: If anyone else sees this, adding a restart delay to my systemd service seems to have fixed my issue. After I made this post, I added a restart delay. the stream has failed several times since, but systemd restarted it and kept it online.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer fleshing out your solution with details, and to accept it to represent that it's the solution you actually used.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a frustrating issue where my FFmpeg command, managed by systemd, kept restarting instantly upon failure, yet YouTube would still drop the video feed. After some troubleshooting, I realized that the rapid restart was likely causing interference with the shutdown process from the failure, resulting in this persistent problem.

Initially, I thought about implementing error monitoring code, but soon realized it was redundant and not addressing the root cause.

Instead, I made a simple adjustment in the systemd service file. I added a 10-second delay before the service restarts upon failure. Since making this change, my stream has encountered failures four times but has stayed online without interruptions!

something like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=FFmpeg Stream Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/ffmpeg.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10 #this!!!!

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a more efficient way to do what I am doing?

Yes; in plenty of ways. Most importantly, log messages can be received as a **continuous stream** without ever needing to re-check every X seconds. For traditional syslog, you could `tail -f` the log file, which would use inotify to output lines as they come; for journald you can do the same with `journalctl -f`. Once you have the log stream, the loop becomes `while read` – the read function will automatically pause until data is available, consuming no resources when idle while at the same time providing instant updates.

```
journalctl -f | while IFS= read -r line; do
    ...
done
```

(Even without this, you could avoid the need to call `date` by using journalctl's built-in support for relative timestamps, i.e. `journalctl -S -1m` for "last minute", or by using its support for resuming at a specific *cursor*, i.e. `journalctl --cursor-file=/tmp/cursor`).

Most likely you don't care about *all* logs, so it would be more efficient to restrict output to only your service's logs – journalctl has the `-u` option to match by service, `-t` to match by "syslog tag" (the name before `[xyz]:`), and you can even do `journalctl /usr/bin/ffmpeg` to filter by executable.

(You might also want to have the script itself log **to** syslog, using `logger` or `systemd-cat`.)

Comment: Why do this outside _after_ things have been passed to the journal, rather than _within_ the individual service, processing ffmpeg's output before passing it through?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: That's more complex – if you have a service that runs `ffmpeg | while`, then you need to manually tee/duplicate its output to syslog if that's wanted; you need to have an outer loop that restarts the inner loop whenever ffmpeg exits (since OP doesn't trust systemd's Restart= to handle that); your script becomes the "main process" that's tracked and killed by systemd; you need to remember to re-allow SIGPIPE in the .service settings; etc. Feels like it would duplicate systemd's job even more than OP's approach already does.

Comment: Eh, `ffmpeg | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; ...` -- that extra `printf` isn't exactly a lot of complexity. Though personally I'd use Python rather than shell for the wrapper. And it only duplicates systemd's job if you tell the wrapper to restart ffmpeg, instead of making the wrapper just _exit_ when it gets an error.

Comment: And if you don't try to restart ffmpeg within the wrapper -- and instead scope it to _only_ enforcing an exit when the desired error is logged -- you don't need to survive SIGPIPE. Tell systemd to enforce shutdown for the cgroup level and that way you also avoid introducing new failure modes re: partial restart; with sensible configuration this doesn't need to be complex or error-prone.